# pyaudio recording multiple channels

Tags: python, audio, wav, microphone, pyaudio

I need to be able to record 3 channels of mic input sound via ASIO using a Presonus 1810c (USB-C) audio interface. I can do it through a DAW, so I know the hardware and drivers work. Not all the inputs show up in the recording devices though, so I can't do it with pyaudio. Is there another way of getting devices like this that don't appear on the list?

This is the code I'm using to get the device list:

```
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
    if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
        n = p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name')
        print("Input Device id",i,"-", n.encode("utf8").decode("cp950", "ignore"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found a solution to this. The `sounddevice` package sees a lot more devices for recording